# Versioning of artifacts - CI/CD

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, continuous-deployment

Build process of java code is currently generating artifacts with name having no version number.

For ex: `serial-framework-SNAPSHOT.jar`

We are currently in build phase of CI/CD  pipeline

All the artifacts generated through maven build has no version number for back-end services, in build phase of CI/CD pipeline

Dependent artifacts that are required to build a specific jar are only stored in JFrog artifactory

---

1)
Does it require versioning of artifacts for Build/QA/prod phase of CI/CD pipeline?

2)
Does it require to store every artifact in JFrog artifactory? Because only dependent artifacts that are required by `pom.xml` during maven build are stored in JFrog

Answer (score 2):

The versioning was well explained in the first answer by snukone.Note the below points which might be helpful regarding versioning

For development always follow the version as “versionNumber-SNAPSHOT “(capital letters)
Eg:-  1.0 -SNAPSHOT

2)  For test/prod branch follow the version as  “versionNumber-RELEASE”
Eg:-  1.0 – RELEASE

a)  Snapshots are mutable, so they are used for development purpose.

b)  Releases are immutable. Once committed we cannot override the artifact in the 
    artifactory. So releases are used for higher environments.

c)  Snapshots capture a work in progress and are used during development. A Snapshot artifact has both a version number such as “1.3.0” or “1.3” and a timestamp. For example, a snapshot artifact for   commons-lang 1.3.0 might have the name commons-lang-1.3.0-20090314.182342-1.jar

So in your case if you are using "serial-framework-SNAPSHOT"  it will store as "serial-framework-version-timestamp.jar" in your artifactory.

Similarly if you are using "serial-framework-RELEASE"  it will store as "serial-framework-version.jar" in your artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

How versioning helps:

- Versioning helps in case you want to restore an older version of your application (due to bugs that are heavily decreasing performance in production)
- If you are running integrationtests on api or ui level, you can specify which versions are fitting together (ie via contract testing: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker)
- Default cleaning processes helps you to prevent your artifactory from huge storage usage

Storing every artifact or not?

My personal experience: Just store the artifacts which are dependencies to other artifacts. Like Libs for example. If you are working with Docker Container you should think about to version the Docker images which you are producing on every build.

Comment: Does, dev pipeline artifact version should be different from QA pipeline geenrating artifact version different from prod pipeline artifact version? if yes, why?

Comment: Am i right that you produce three different artifacts in three different Pipelines? What are the differences of the three artifacts? If for example dev pipe generates a Webapplication WAR and qa pipeline Testresults you could use maven classifier to distinguish between both.

Comment: Dev pipeline generates a WAR having unit+integration testing results. QA pipeline is only considered on forthcoming of release date. Nothing much different in terms of changes. Most of the integration testing should be done in Dev pipeline

Comment: Is it possible to use the same artifacts generated in your dev pipe in the qa and prod pipe? So you are saving resources. We habe a ci and a delivery pipe. In the CI the application is build and tested. In the Delivery pipe we only check that certain rules for the artifacts are true  and deploy them in prod. If you are using the maven release plugin you could controll the creation  of releases via Parameter or having one for snapshots and one for releases.